# Why is my if statement not returning the correct result?

Tags: java, arrays, debugging

Is there anything wrong with my code structure wise that is causing me to get errors?
I think I fixed my for loops and the parameters and everything is fine now but I am still getting errors?

```
  public static int indexOf(int[] list, int searchValue) throws BadArrayException 
    {
        int indexValue = 0;

        if(list == null)
            throw new BadArrayException("Array is null");
        else if((list.length) == 0)
            return -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < (list.length); i++){
            if(list[i] == searchValue)
                indexValue = i;
        }
        return indexValue;
    }

    public static int lastIndexOf(int[] list, int searchValue) throws BadArrayException
    {
        int indexValue = 0;
        int last = (list.length-1);

        if(list.length == 0)
            return -1;

        for(int i = last; i >= 0; i--){
            if(list[i] == searchValue)
                indexValue = i;
        }
        return indexValue;        
    }
}
```

What I am getting:

Testing ArrayUtils class exception handling - 2/07/2014

--- Testing minValue method ---

Getting minVal of a null array
  OK - minValue threw exception for null array: BadArrayException

Getting minVal of an empty array
  OK - minValue threw exception for empty array: BadArrayException

Getting minVal() of: [10]
  OK - expected minValue to return 10 and got: 10

Getting minVal() of: [20,30]
  OK - expected minValue to return 20 and got: 20

Getting minVal() of: [40,30]
  OK - expected minValue to return 30 and got: 30

Getting minVal() of: [10,10]
  OK - expected minValue to return 10 and got: 10

Getting minVal() of: [15,25,35]
  OK - expected minValue to return 15 and got: 15

Getting minVal() of: [25,20,30]
  OK - expected minValue to return 20 and got: 20

Getting minVal() of: [50,40,30]
  OK - expected minValue to return 30 and got: 30

Getting minVal() of: [50,-10,40,-25,50,40,30]
  OK - expected minValue to return -25 and got: -25

Getting minVal() of: [200,50,-40,60,-15,30,75]
  OK - expected minValue to return -40 and got: -40

--- Testing copyRange method ---

Getting copyRange of a null array
  OK - copyRange threw exception for null array: BadArrayException

Getting copyRange(list,-1) of: []
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -1

Getting copyRange(list,0) of: []
  OK - copyRange copied the array correctly as []

Getting copyRange(list,1) of: []
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 1

Getting copyRange(list,-1) of: [20]
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -1

Getting copyRange(list,0) of: [20]
  OK - copyRange copied the array correctly as [20]

Getting copyRange(list,1) of: [20]
  OK - copyRange copied the array correctly as []

Getting copyRange(list,2) of: [20]
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 2

Getting copyRange(list,-1) of: [10,15]
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -1

Getting copyRange(list,0) of: [10,15]
  OK - copyRange copied the array correctly as [10,15]

Getting copyRange(list,1) of: [10,15]
  OK - copyRange copied the array correctly as [15]

Getting copyRange(list,2) of: [10,15]
  OK - copyRange copied the array correctly as []

Getting copyRange(list,3) of: [10,15]
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 3

Getting copyRange(list,-1) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: -1

Getting copyRange(list,0) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  OK - copyRange copied the array correctly as [30,35,40,45,50]

Getting copyRange(list,1) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  OK - copyRange copied the array correctly as [35,40,45,50]

Getting copyRange(list,2) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  OK - copyRange copied the array correctly as [40,45,50]

Getting copyRange(list,3) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  OK - copyRange copied the array correctly as [45,50]

Getting copyRange(list,4) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  OK - copyRange copied the array correctly as [50]

Getting copyRange(list,5) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  OK - copyRange copied the array correctly as []

Getting copyRange(list,6) of: [30,35,40,45,50]
  OK - copyRange threw exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 6

--- Testing indexOf and lastIndexOf method ---

Getting indexOf of a null array
  OK - indexOf threw exception for null array: BadArrayException

Getting lastIndexOf of a null array
  ERROR - lastIndexOf threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Getting indexOf(5) of: []
  OK - expected indexOf to return -1 and got: -1

Getting lastIndexOf(5) of: []
  OK - expected lastIndexOf to return -1 and got: -1

Getting indexOf(20) of: [20]
  OK - expected indexOf to return 0 and got: 0

Getting indexOf(25) of: [20]
  ERROR - expected indexOf to return -1 but got: 0

Getting lastIndexOf(20) of: [20]
  OK - expected lastIndexOf to return 0 and got: 0

Getting lastIndexOf(25) of: [20]
  ERROR - expected lastIndexOf to return -1 but got: 0

Getting indexOf(5) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected indexOf to return 0 but got: 6

Getting indexOf(10) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected indexOf to return 1 but got: 7

Getting indexOf(15) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected indexOf to return 2 but got: 8

Getting indexOf(20) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected indexOf to return 3 but got: 9

Getting indexOf(0) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected indexOf to return -1 but got: 0

Getting lastIndexOf(5) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected lastIndexOf to return 6 but got: 0

Getting lastIndexOf(10) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected lastIndexOf to return 7 but got: 1

Getting lastIndexOf(15) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected lastIndexOf to return 8 but got: 2

Getting lastIndexOf(20) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected lastIndexOf to return 9 but got: 3

Getting lastIndexOf(0) of: [5,10,15,20,10,15,5,10,15,20]
  ERROR - expected lastIndexOf to return -1 but got: 0

Done - press enter key to end program

THESE SHOULD all be OK not errors
Am I approaching this code incorrectly?
Sorry I asked about this before but not in the correct manner

Comment: `int last = (list.length-1);` maybe?

Comment: I think the key thing you're doing wrong is failing to debug your code with a debugger and/or logging/tracing.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you are missing is null check of the array in `lastIndexOf`.
But the main error is that you don't break out of the loop once you find the first match (this is true for both methods).

Oh, and `int indexValue = 0;` is wrong. You should initialize it to -1 (since that's the value that indicates "not found").

Taking all these things into account, I think this should work :

```
    public static int indexOf(int[] list, int searchValue) throws BadArrayException 
    {
        int indexValue = -1;

        if(list == null)
            throw new BadArrayException("Array is null");
        else if((list.length) == 0)
            return -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < (list.length); i++){
            if(list[i] == searchValue) {
                indexValue = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return indexValue;
    }

    public static int lastIndexOf(int[] list, int searchValue) throws BadArrayException
    {
        int indexValue = -1;

        if(list == null)
            throw new BadArrayException("Array is null");

        int last = (list.length-1);

        if(list.length == 0)
            return -1;

        for(int i = last; i >= 0; i--){
            if(list[i] == searchValue) {
                indexValue = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return indexValue;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code have three problems,

- The **NULL** validation over the parameter called `list` at `lastIndexOf` function, is missing. If you aggregate that validation you will avoid the error:

> ERROR - lastIndexOf threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

- For both functions, you must initialize the var `indexValue` with `-1` instead of `0`, to avoid:

> ERROR - expected indexOf to return -1 but got: 0

- For both functions, once you find the first ocurrence of the `searchValue` you must return the index `i`. With this change you will avoid errors like:

> ERROR - expected indexOf to return 2 but got: 8

With this three changes your code must look like this:

```
public static int indexOf(int[] list, int searchValue) throws BadArrayException 
{
    int indexValue = -1;

    if(list == null)
        throw new BadArrayException("Array is null");

    //Not neccessary
    /*else if((list.length) == 0)
        return -1;*/

    for(int i = 0; i < (list.length); i++){
        if(list[i] == searchValue)
            return i;
    }
    return indexValue;
}

public static int lastIndexOf(int[] list, int searchValue) throws BadArrayException
{
    int indexValue = -1;

    if(list == null)
        throw new BadArrayException("Array is null");

    int last = (list.length-1);

    //Not neccessary
    /*if(list.length == 0)
        return -1;*/

    for(int i = last; i >= 0; i--){
        if(list[i] == searchValue)
            return i;
    }
    return indexValue;        
}
```

Notice that some validation you made in your code are not anymore necessary if `indexValue` is initialized to `-1`.

Finally I recommend you to use some debugging tools or run your code with paper and pen, to discover the reasons of errors.

Hope to help you.
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

when you find the value, you should break from the loop:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < (list.length); i++){
        if(list[i] == searchValue) {
            indexValue = i;
            **break;**
        }
    }
```